# Creating a digital signature in Ruby without command line

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl

I'd like to migrate this unix script o ruby:

```
echo -n "loremipsum" | openssl dgst -md5 -hex -sign keys/#02299991.privKey.pem
```

The result is the following:

```
(stdin)= 08d9d6496a5146bc1955ad35c884e3b843d441eebc9ed7908b220e9414132dad57dc0f4744e5ec4a9a819e20f4099e2c90186b4684b3b52d1409dd4ca5bc86e7c16dbb64e6cf41d695a7e979744616fe92e5347a7acbb1e1da902d3cfc629927adf3e119f33d2cbc89f90f9494d44becbf93855d09460a67e2615e7d8df7e4f8
```

I'm using the following code:

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("keys/#02299991.privKey.pem"))
md5_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest 'loremipsum' # result: 65a73f29730d3519bd7dd98ab954ed56
key.private_encrypt md5_hash
```

And this is the problem private_encrypt creates a very different hash from the one that i generated with command line:

```
"B62\xDA\x80\xF9\xFF]\xCE;\a\xB3)fC\xA8v\x9EM5\xF8Z\xA9\x00\b\xA4\x95 \x84\x8A\xD6:\xDA\xCE\x1D\x01\x9F&\xEB\xD5\xD6\xDF\xC0\v\xD8i\xA0\x86\x8E\e`\x98\xB9\x19\xEC\xA7\x8A\\.\xD1\xCC\xFC\x93\x1C\xFF\xFFh\xAFw\t\xFF\xC8Z\xEC\xBDP\x9C_\x03%\x85:\x04\x1C=\xF3\xAC\xE1\x917TO\x94\xB2\x9Fd`3\x98\x04\x93\xBFS\\\xD1Z\xF9\xBD\x91\xE3\xA1:\xA3B22U_FI'`0i\x8D(\x9B`"
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Your `openssl` command is generating a signed MD5 digest from the data. Your Ruby code is generating an (unsigned) MD5 digest and then encrypting the hex digest with RSA. Those are really different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `openssl` command and your Ruby code do very different things. Your `openssl` command says "generate an MD5 digest signed with my RSA key and print it in hex format." Your Ruby code says "generate an (unsigned) MD5 digest in hex format and then encrypt it with my RSA key." Digest generation and encryption are not the same thing and are not going to give you the same result.

The Ruby equivalent to your `openssl` command is this:

```
data = 'loremipsum'
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("keys/#02299991.privKey.pem"))
signature = pkey.sign(digest, data)
hex_signature = signature.unpack('H*').first
```

The first four lines are practically verbatim from the docs for [`OpenSSL::PKey::PKey#sign`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/PKey.html#method-i-sign). That method returns a binary string (I couldn't find a way to get a hex string directly; if anyone knows a way please leave a comment), so we have to use [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html) to turn it into a hex string. (`unpack` returns an array, ergo `.first`.)